# IntegrityError at /quizmaker/ (1048, "Column 'id_id' cannot be null")

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to make quiz making application, since am new to django am unable to build the logic for saving foreign key field in database table. Someone please  help me for the same.

models.py
In models.py , class quiztitle is for title of the quiz and id(foreign key,User model) of user who created that quiz.
class question is for question along with 4 options and the correct answer. Quizid(foreign key,quiztitle  model) and id(foreign key,User model)
class answer is for the answer submitted by user who take the quiz.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class quiztitle(models.Model):

    Quiz_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Quiz_title = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    id= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class question(models.Model):

    Qid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Quiz_id = models.ForeignKey(quiztitle,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Qques = models.TextField()
    Qoption1 = models.TextField()
    Qoption2 = models.TextField()
    Qoption3 = models.TextField()
    Qoption4 = models.TextField()
    QAnswer = models.TextField()


class answer(models.Model):

    Ansid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Qid = models.ForeignKey(question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Quiz_id = models.ForeignKey(quiztitle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Answer = models.TextField()
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
   class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import question ,quiztitle
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import  authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import CreateUserForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import  authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
# Create your views here.

@login_required(login_url='home')
def handle_quiz(request):

    if request.method=="POST":
        # get post parameters
        id = request.POST.get('id')
        Quiz_title = request.POST.get('Quiz_title')
        Quiz_id = request.POST.get('Quiz_id')
        Qid = request.POST.get('Qid')
        Qques = request.POST.get('Qques')
        Qoption1 = request.POST.get('Qoption1')
        Qoption2 = request.POST.get('Qoption2')
        Qoption3 = request.POST.get('Qoption3')
        Qoption4 = request.POST.get('Qoption4')
        QAnswer = request.POST.get('QAnswer')

   

        #I guess here is the mistake in saving the data in the mysql database

        title = quiztitle(Quiz_title=Quiz_title,Quiz_id=Quiz_id,id=id)
        title.save()
        detail = question(Qid=Qid,Quiz_id=Quiz_id,id=id,Qques=Qques,Qoption1=Qoption1,Qoption2=Qoption2,Qoption3=Qoption3,Qoption4=Qoption4,QAnswer=QAnswer)
        detail.save()

        messages.success(request,"Your question has been added succesfully ")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/quizmaker')


    return render(request,"createquiz.html")

def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')#redirect to login page

def home_page(request):
    return render(request,'Home.html')

def registerPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            
                messages.success(request, 'account has been created successfully for username' + username)
                return redirect('login')

        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request,'register.html',context)

def handle_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('quizmaker')
            else:
                messages.info(request, 'Incorrect Username or Password')
        context = {}
        return render(request, 'login.html', context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
def handle_response(request):
    data= question.objects.all()
    return render(request, "student.html", {"messages": data})
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
# Register your models here.
class quizadmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['Qid','Quiz_id','Qques','Qoption1','Qoption2','Qoption3','Qoption4','QAnswer']

admin.site.register(question,quizadmin)
admin.site.register(quiztitle)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you guess your issue lies at `title` and `detail`.

To set a value to the `ForeignKey` you need an object. You can use instead an field with `_id` at the end.

> Behind the scenes, Django appends **"_id"** to the field name to
> create its database column name, see [**Django ForeignKey**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation)

**It must be**:

```
title = quiztitle.objects.create(
    Quiz_title=Quiz_title,
    Quiz_id=Quiz_id,
    User_id_id=id # here 
) 

detail = question.objects.create(
    Quiz_id_id=Quiz_id, User_id_id=id # and here,
    Qid=Qid, Qques=Qques, Qoption1=Qoption1, 
    Qoption2=Qoption2, Qoption3=Qoption3,
    Qoption4=Qoption4, QAnswer=QAnswer
)
```

---

I suggest you to use [**Django ModelForm**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) here.

Based on the above, I recommend you also to rename your ForeignKey fields:

- **id** > to **user**
- **Quiz_id** > to **quiztitle**

[**Model style**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style) ([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style)):

- Use **InitialCaps** for class names (or for factory functions that return
  classes).
- Field names should be all **lowercase**, using underscores instead of
  camelCase.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've added those lines to views.py but now new error is there: TypeError at /quizmaker/ 
quiztitle() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id_id' .

Comment: I want to store all the foreign key fields in database table. Logic from views.py is not working for the same. Kindly help me ,am a new user to django.

Comment: @aishwaryayadav, I edited my answer. Is it id or User_id Foreignkey User. Your second error request doesn’t have quiztitle use instead `detail.Quiz_id = title`.

Comment: my bad, its id only. Now it is working well. Thank You soo much you saved me It's my minor project.